# Get the total correct answer in exam (create a view table mysql)

Tags: mysql

Hello I want to create a view table that count the correct answer of the each users. The schema of my table is something like this.

User exam table

```
user_id     | questionnaire_id | answer_id
1           | 1                |    3       
1           | 2                |    1       
2           | 1                |    4
2           | 2                |    2
```

Answer table

```
answer_id   questionnaire_id    is_correct
1           1                   1
2           1                   0
3           1                   0
4           1                   0
1           2                   0
2           2                   1
3           2                   0
4           2                   0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because is_correct has a value of 1, you can sum and derive their total score:

```
select e.user_id, sum(a.is_correct) score
from exam_table e 
left join answer_table a 
  on a.questionnaire_id = e.questionnaire_id 
  and a.answer_id = e.answer_id
group by e.user_id;
```

[Here is a functional example](http://rextester.com/IESI7850) with a new user with a perfect score